# Fedora module-native-protocol-tcp lost on login

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio, pipewire

On Fedora 39 I have the following...

`cat /etc/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.d/50-network-party.conf`

```
context.exec = [
    { path = "pactl" args = "load-module module-native-protocol-tcp" }
]
```

which works great... except after I login it's lost and I have to execute `pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp` manually again.

Am I missing some config or something?